# Statics are inaccessible from within dynamically loaded Controller

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a plugin system here that checks assemblys for implementations of a base class. One base class is supposed to provide an API, but when I hit a Controller, static variables forget their values and always return their default value.

The plugin system creates module instances like this:

```
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(@"absolute\path\to\TestModule.dll");
var types = assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(ModuleBase)));

ModuleBase instance = (ModuleBase)Activator.CreateInstance(types.FirstOrDefault());
instance.Execute();
```

That's working nice so far. The plugin base type is as minimal as it could get:

```
    public abstract class ModuleBase
    {
        public abstract void Execute();
    }
```

Now I implement a plugin for that in a different project:

```
public class TestModule : ModuleBase
{
    public static int StaticTest;

    public override void Execute()
    {
        StaticTest = 3; // variable is initialized with some non-default value

        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
               .UseStartup<Startup>()
               .Build()
               .RunAsync(cancellationTokenSource.Token);
     }
 }
```

with the Startup.cs class looking like this:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseMvc();
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
    }
}
```

Nothing fancy, really. However, when I now implement a Controller that is accessing my `StaticTest` variable, it's value is 0:

```
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [Route("Test")]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<int> GetStatics()
    {
        return TestModule.StaticTest;
    }
}
```

If I drop the plugin approach and instead create the `WebHost` from a console application directly, everything works as expected and the Controller returns 3.

I suspected MVC to launch controllers in a different `AppDomain`, but that does not seem to be the case, as `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName` and `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Id` do not change and `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DomainUnload` is not invoked.

Any ideas are welcome, I am totally clueless now and I feel I missed some essential concept of this whole thing.

Comment: `That's working nice so far. Now I implement a plugin for that in a different project:` this. What do you mean? How do you know that execute gets called? Do you have any logging? Are you sure (like really, really sure) that the StaticTest property you are referencing is in the right type and is not a similarly named property on the base type? What you describe seems impossible, so I would assume there is something going on.

Comment: @A. Chiesa: I'm sure I'm referencing the static from `TestModule`, because the variable is not defined in the base type. For clarity, I've updated the question accordingly. If I wrap the `TestModule` into a console application and run it with `new TestModule().Execute()`, everything works as expected.

Comment: So now the question is: how do you know that the `TestModule.Execute` method is called in MVC? Are you logging (to the Console or whatever logging tool you use) something inside the method? Are you sure the type found is `TestModule`?

Comment: Well, since the project is launched from Visual Studio, I simply set a break point in `TestModule.Execute`. I've also investigated `types` in the loader (the first code snippet), it's indeed a list with a single `TestModule` type in it.

Comment: It's really awkward, I've been using C# for more than 10 years now, and yet I have absolutely no clue what's going on here.

Comment: Try changing the field StaticTest into a property and put a breakpoint in the setter (and just for the sake of completeness into the getter too). Possibly you are resetting it somewhere?

Comment: Tested that, and that's not the case. The breakpoint within the setter is just called from `StaticTest = 3` :-/

Comment: Are you hosting on IIS or something else? I can't reference any documentation, but, when I used IIS for Asp.NET hosting I discovered that some recycling operations would reset static members. Could you setup a recurring task or a watch in the debugger highlighting the value change?

Answer (score 0):

You have an ivar named `Test`, and you're accessing a member named `StaticTest`, which doesn't seem to be defined. My assumption is that you misnamed the ivar in this question and it's supposed to be `StaticTest`, not `Test`.

Based on that assumption, the issue is that you've cast your dynamically created object to `ModuleBase`, but `StaticTest` exists on `TestModule`. Therefore, you cannot access `StaticTest` unless you cast to `TestModule`, because that's where it's defined.

**EDIT**

Sorry, I wasn't paying close enough attention to the controller code. The real issue is similar to the above, but has to do with `Execute`. You haven't shown where that's called, but I'm assuming you're calling it *somewhere* or the answer as to why the static has no value would be immensely obvious. However, if your instance is typed as `ModuleBase`, it's going to call `ModuleBase.Execute()`, not `TestModule.Execute()`, even if it's actually a `TestModule` instance. Only if you're working with something actually typed as `TestModule` will the correct `Execute` override be called.

Comment: Thanks @Chris Pratt for pointing that out, I've edited my question accordingly. That slipped through while writing this down. I have some minimal code that isolates the problem, and I've missed to rename the variable consistently. The missing `Execute` was just malformatted below the code block. The variable is initialized, and not overwritten in between.